# How to use parallel computing for a custom optimization function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, neural-network

Currently I am trying to train a neural network of following configuration
Input Layer size -> 307200
Hidden Layer size -> 50
Output Layer size -> 10

I use the optimization function provided by coursera 'fmincg' to train the network. Since the network size is big, its taking a long time. So I tried to use parallel computing toolbox in matlab for this. Matlab has a documentation for using parallel computing for optimization functions provided by matlab.

But I don't know how to use parallel computing for a custom optimization function for a user defined function.

If someone can throw some light on this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult task. You would have to re-write the optimization solver itself. It would be much easier to parallelize at a coarser level. For example, you might repeatedly train the network to try different initialization conditions, hyperparameter values, etc. In this case, it would be easy to parallelize by training multiple networks simultaneously with the different values. There are many other approaches for speeding up training that could be worth looking into, that involve changing how you initialize/optimize/compute things.